# Jquery group photo hover effect

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have seen (or thought I saw) a way to use Jquery on a group photo to allow fade out all but one area of a photo and show a caption. The idea is to allow people to mouse-over specific faces in a group photo and see information about them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an image map would probably be your best bet? How about a plugin like this:

http://drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight

[JQuery Highlight plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight)

[Demo of plugin](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html)